# How to display an async list in view using Rows and make it a button?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class MicrocontrollersList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: 
    );
  }
  getMicrocontrollers() async {
    String uri = 'Uri';
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'Token';
    final value = prefs.getString(key);
    var response = await http.get(uri, headers: {"Token": value});
    var responseBody = response.body; // This is an array of objects I wish to display this as a list.
  }
```

The result body output is in the form

```
 [{Name: 'Trishant', minors: ['minor1', 'minor2', 'minor3']}, {Name: 'Trishant2', minors: ['minor4', 'minor5']}]
```

Comment: you need to use stateful widget, and BloC pattern or providers to make it work properly. Read more here: https://medium.com/flutterpub/architecting-your-flutter-project-bd04e144a8f1

Comment: @Trisshant Please check the below solution and let me know in case of concern

Comment: It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can use FutureBuilder widget it get a future till your method response and has builder to create a widget when the method response and get the snapshot if your method was not completed yet you build a waiter and if the data responded you build you ListView.builder is an easy way to create a list view if you have an existed list.

```
var responseBody;//make this variable global to use it in our list view in builder method.
getMicrocontrollers() async {
    String uri = 'Uri';
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final key = 'Token';
    final value = prefs.getString(key);
    var response = await http.get(uri, headers: {"Token": value});
    responseBody = response.body;
    return responseBody
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _incrementCounter(),//you send it any type of future but in this situation you can just send your method.
        builder: (context,snapshot){
          if (snapshot.data==null){//check if the method is returned data or not.
            return CircularProgressIndicator();//this show a nice waiter.
          }else{//if is returned
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: response.length,//here you say how many time will loop the itemBuilder.
              itemBuilder:(context,index){//here you build your list view.
              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(response[index]['Name']),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      for(String buttonName in response[index]['minors'])//this for reapiting the widget.
                      RaisedButton(child: Text(buttonName,),onPressed: (){},)
                      ],
                  ),
                ],
              );
            } );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: a sample of it]

you can get more information about both `FuturBuilder` and `ListView.builder` here:
[Futur Builder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo)
[ListView.builder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJpkjHGiI5A&vl=en)

Comment: Where is the defining response variable?

Comment: we just want the responseBody so I define it inside the class look at the first statement of my code.

Comment: Can you help me by using screen share?

Comment: I sent an email for you